# Using UI to turn on data and leaflet display on and off

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I have set up a sample of this problem in ui.R and server.R files. This is the ui.R file. There are three random data sets. The one with markers will be displayed no matter what is done with the UI. The other two data sets should get plotted only if requested as "Circles".

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Main Title Here"),
    sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput('Circles', 'Show Locations', TRUE)
    ),

    mainPanel(
        leafletOutput("map")
    )

)
```

The map is generated by server.R, which follows below. This generates the random data and the latitude and longitude locations.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(ggplot2)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
             addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
             addMarkers(runif(20,-75,-74),
                  runif(20, 41, 42))
    })
    observe({
        proxy <- leafletProxy("map")
        if (input$Circles == TRUE) {
            proxy %>% addCircles(runif(20,-75,-74),
                           runif(20, 41, 42),
                           group = "Circles",
                           color = "red") %>%
            addCircles(runif(20,-75,-74),
                   runif(20, 41, 42),
                   group = "Circles",
                   color = "blue") %>%
            addLegend(
                position = "bottomright",
                colors = c("red", "blue"),
                labels = c("Group 1", "Group 2")
            )
      # cannot put group or label on legend.
      } else {
          proxy %>% hideGroup("Circles")
          # %>% hideGroup("Group 2")
      }
    })
})
```

Displaying the circles is turned on (TRUE) as the program starts. I am seeing two major problems here. First, the circles can be turned off, but that is the end of any UI control. The problem is that they cannot be turned on again. If I try starting checkboxInput as FALSE, the UI control will not turn it on. I don't know if that is standard, or if I am doing something wrong.

The second major problem is that I cannot program the legend to be turned off along with the circles. The circles are turned off with the hideGroup() function. This is rejected for use on the legend. I have taken the command I tried and turned it into a comment line. Go ahead and remove the # sign so that you can see the errors that it creates. I have not yet found an alternative.

Comment: the opposite of `hideGroup` is `showGroup`. Once you've hidden them, you need to 'show' them again if you want to see them.

Comment: The original creation of these circles was with the command "addCircles()". Would I replace these with showGroup, or is that combined somehow with addCircles?

Comment: you probably need to `addCircles()` to the original `leaflet()` call. Then the `proxy` events either `show` or `hide` depending on the `input$Circles` condition

Comment: I will try that. Any way to hide the legend?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank SymblixAU for sending me in the right direction. The problem with hideGroup and showGroup is that both functions take a small number of variables. The data display has to be pre-defined by other commands, such as addCircles or addMarkers. I finally have a working version, shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        leaflet() %>%
            addTiles(group = "OpenStreetMap") %>%
            addMarkers(runif(20,-75,-74),
                   runif(20, 41, 42))
    })

    proxy <- leafletProxy("map")

    proxy %>% addCircles(runif(20,-75,-74),
                     runif(20, 41, 42),
                     group = "Circles",
                     color = "red") %>%
    addCircles(runif(20,-75,-74),
               runif(20, 41, 42),
               group = "Circles",
               color = "blue")

# now we can show or hide depending on UI
    observe({
        if (input$Circles == TRUE) {
            proxy %>% showGroup("Circles")
        } else {
            proxy %>% hideGroup("Circles")
        }
    })

})
```

I have also abandoned the use of the legend. I have yet to find software that will adequately control the number of legends being added to the plot, so I will have to describe the use of colors another way, perhaps in the text.